# waiting for process to finish

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

i have a program in c# which run some process for example

```
        generate.exe a.tif -o myfile.txt
```

and the next line after the following my code will need to access the following myfile.txt.
how do i know when it is ready? i know that it will generate the file for sure, but how to set the next line so that it executes only after the file myfile.txt is generated. thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Will generate.exe ends after generating myfile.txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your process exits **only after** generating the file you can use Process.WaitForExit()

You can check also this kb article for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369

Answer (score 1):

If the process ends right after creating the file then you can use Process.WaitForExit as @Naveen suggested. 
If process does not end then:

1. Either you will have to introduce the IPC ( ex: events) to indicate the file creation.
2. Or Poll the file creation by opening at some fixed amount of time. ( weak solution,I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Process.HasExited will give you the answer you are looking for.